Какая из 2 функций по скорости выполнения будет быстрее и почему?
Есть вот такие 2 функции:
1.
#include <iostream>
int ReturnIntX(int x) {
    if (x == 1) {
        return x;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = ReturnIntX(a);
}
 




#include <iostream>
int ReturnInt1(int x) {
    if (x == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = ReturnInt1(a);
}
 

Имеет ли вляиние на это предыдущий запуск/фоновые процессы?
Мне интересно узнать, что будет быстрее: возвращение переданного аргумента, или литеральное значение? Ведь если так подумать, что переменная x, хоть и пустая может иметь "вес", а если ещё и значения, то "вес" увеличивается
P.s.: Могли бы подсказать библиотеки для самостоятельной проверки?

Зевая... Компилятор выдаст одинаковый код.

@AlexanderPetrov не понимаю вас. Что значит "выдаст одинаковый код". И зачем мне нужен код компилятора, если мне интересен ответ на вопрос.

https://godbolt.org/z/r4ashdef9 - оцените, во что компилятор превратил код. В окне справа ассемблерные инструкции. / Уберите опцию -O и посмотрите результат без оптимизации.

"зачем мне нужен код компилятора" - а это и есть ответ: без разницы :)

Это не будет работать. Если x != 1, то из ReturnIntX нет возврата и управление провалится дальше...

Если функция ReturnIntX получает аргумент x не равный единице, выполнение функции завершится без возврата значения. Язык C++ считает такую ситуацию неопределённым поведением. Компилятор предполагает что программист не допускает неопределённого поведения. То есть, фактически компилятор предполагает что x всегда будет передан в функцию со значением равным единице. А тогда можно сделать оптимизацию и вернуть из функции единицу, а условный оператор удалить. Более того, можно удалить и вызов функции, так как результат её выполнения известен заранее. Что компилятор и делает: все вызовы функции в коде заменяются на литеральное значение - единицу.
Это верно для обоих вариантов функции и делает ваш вопрос бессодержательным: кода функции в программе нет, интересоваться скоростью её работы бессмысленно.
P.S. Скорость работы функции вообще условность. Вы можете измерять скорость работы программы целиком и по этой скорости делать вывод о "скорости функции". Но "скорость функции" в другой программе может проявиться по-другому. Требуется большой опыт чтобы определить надежно "скорость функции".

Всё что сказано ввами - какой-то бред, если честно. Мне было интересно узнать, что будет быстрее возвращение переданного аргумента, или литеральное значения. Ведь если так подумать, что переменная x, хоть и пустая может иметь "вес", а если ещё и значения, то "вес" увеличивается. Вопрос заключался в этом. А то что вы написали - какая-то чушь собачья.
P.s. Мне не нужны сверхъгениальные решения по измерению. Хотя бы для базового понимания, какие-нибудь способы определить скорость выполнения кусков кода

@Denis Для базового понимания: посмотрите время перед выполнением, и время после. О всяких факторах, типа оптимизации, размещения в кеше процессора, да просто погрешностях измерения и еще 1001 факторе ничего не говорю, чтобы не получить реакцию "какой-то бред" :)

@Denis, то что вы меня не понимаете означает что мы по разному смотрим на проблему. Это нормально. Поставьте минус моему ответу, через некоторое время посмотрите кто к вам присоединится.

@Denis, повторю основную мысль: вы хотели измерить разумную вещь - что быстрее вернуть, константу или значение аргумента? Так можно ставить вопрос. Но код, который вы написали, не помогает решить этот вопрос - об этом мой ответ. Вставьте ваш коментарий в вопрос, в начало. Исправьте код так чтобы компилятор не мог его удалить, вопрос получит смысл, а мой ответ станет бессмыслицей. Но пока мой "бредовый" ответ хорошо отвечает на ваш вопрос.

«Компилятор предполагает что программист не допускает неопределённого поведения» — тут скорее «стандарт считает, что программист [подходит к работе ответственно и] не допускает неопределённого поведения». Разрешение игнорировать UB прописано в стандарте.

@VladD, я имел в виду, что компилятор можно так настроить что он будет пользоваться UB для оптимизации. ТС не понимает тонкостей, я нарисовал самую страшную и строгую картину, когда компилятор буквально следует стандарту в самой жесткой его форме.

Насколько я понимаю, стандарт неявно разрешает пользоваться UB для оптимизации (именно для этого UB и придумано), поэтому то, что некоторые компиляторы возможно настроить, чтобы они поменьше этим пользовались — деталь реализации этих компиляторов. Программа с UB может всё.

Насколько я вижу, в этой функции серьезная ошибка. Если x не равен 1, то в ней отсутствует return(!!!). На практике g++ (по крайней мере в Arm) обычно генерит в таком случае код в котором отсутствует возврат из функции и при выполнении начинает исполняться следующая функция (!)

@avp, формально это не ошибка. Если программист всегда вызывает эту функцию с единицей в параметре, неопределённого поведения нет. Всё в порядке.

Современные компиляторы давно уже не компилируют ваш код построчно. Задача компилятора — найти самый эффективный код, который будет вести себя так же, как и ваш исходник.
Поскольку в вашем случае (отвлекаясь от UB) смысл обоих фрагментов одинаковый, то и компилироваться он будет одинаково. Как именно — зависит от конкретного компилятора, а также от целевой платформы.
Вот например, для интеловской платформы clang произвёл одинаковый код: https://godbolt.org/z/EPKqxKP75:
mov     eax, 1
cmp     edi, 1
je      .EXIT

Компилятор вообще имеет право менять ваш код как угодно, только бы результат был таким же (за вычетом UB). Вот тут он, например, свернул цикл в обычное умножение.

Если вы хотите оптимизировать код, то не стоит заботиться о подобных нанооптимизациях, компилятор умеет это делать намного лучше вас. Оптимизируйте алгоритмы и структуры данных, которые вы используете.

В случае натягивания абстрактной совы на виртуальный глобус  ответить на этот вопрос невозможно.
Например, в данном конкретном случае функция будет эквивалентна return 1; из-за неопределённого поведения, и, возможно, после подстановки вообще уйдет из кода, просто где-то в регистр запишется единица.
В теории  все зависит от того как из вашего буквального значения (литерального?) получается итоговый объект и насколько это "дороже" копирования, и насколько возможно подстановка. в случае исправленного кода.
Однако насколько RVO быстрее копирования заранее сказать нельзя.
Можно только гарантировать, что NRVO на аргументы функции не распространяется,  поэтому в не-consteval контексте не-ссылочный аргумент всегда будет скопирован, а не создан "на месте".
Остальное могут сказать только замеры производительности или чтение кода, созданного компилятором для конкретной ситуации.
